# regex to capture upto first delim, but excluding

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to match upto first ":"

```
Servers:
auth4.localhost\t2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe96:beac
auth1.dev.srv 2a00:1098:0:80:1000::10
```

Excepted:

```
Servers:
```

But I'm not getting only Servers, I'm also getting the following ipv6 address like below:

```
Servers:
auth4.localhost\t2600:
auth1.dev.srv 2a00:
```

Current Regex I'm using

```
(^.*?[^:]):
```

I there a way I match with ":" but not IPv6 addresses?

thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand you wish to match up to the first colon for some lines but not others. What are the requirements of a line for it to be matched up to the first colon? I suggest your example include some lines that are to be matched and some lines that are not to be matched, with explanations for why each example line is to be matched or not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I would like to match any link that has a field: (can include space, dash, etc, until the delim ":", and only until the first ":". But if the line just has a ipv6 address (which includes ":") I dont want to capture that

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what is your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it with the below:

```
^[^\S\r\n]*?[^\:\.\n]+?\:
```

- Thanks

Comment: You don't need to escape the colon.